# CKEditor4-react : add EasyImage plugin without cloud url

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor4-react and want to add EasyImage plugin but without using cloudservice URL. As an alternate I have a folder hosted on server where it should upload the image. But it doesn't work.

I followed the documentation to use EasyImage plugin - 
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/easyimage.html
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-cloudServices_uploadUrl

and as per it "cloudServices_uploadUrl" is mandatory for EasyImage plugin.

Can I provide an alternate URL which is hosted on our server so the images can be saved and fetched from there?

The old version of CKEditor4 was used in one of our legacy apps built in Knockout.js where it is being used in a similar way consuming the ckeditor/plugin/simpleuploads.

But i didn't find any such plugin in the current CKEditor4.12 version

```
config: {
                toolbar: [
                    { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'] },
                    { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
                    { name: 'insert', items: ['Link', 'EasyImageUpload', 'Table'] },
                    { name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'FontSize', 'Font', 'Format', 'TextColor', 'BGColor'] },
                    { name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Blockquote', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'] }
                ],
                height: 600,
                width: 950,
                extraPlugins: 'easyimage',
                removePlugins: 'image',
                //cloudServices_uploadUrl: 'https://33333.cke-cs.com/easyimage/upload/', //this is a demo ckeditor cloud service URL
                cloudServices_uploadUrl: '/app/Data' //this is folder hosted on our server which is accessible as localhost/app/data
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

[Easy Image plugin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/easyimage.html) for CKEditor 4 only supports Cloud Services for uploading images at the moment, so `cloudServices_uploadUrl` is mandatory and should point to [CKEditor Cloud Services](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-cloud-services/) endpoint as the [documentation says](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-cloudServices_uploadUrl).

If you would like to upload and store images on your own server you may use [CKFinder](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_ckfinder_integration.html), your [custom upload adapter](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_file_browser_api.html) or look for any 3rd-party solution which satisfy your needs.

Comment: CKFinder and custom upload adapter both do not have a react wrapper as per the documentation. Is there any other way around to use the CKEditor so that the images can be uploaded  on our server? 
Our application is built in React 16.

Comment: What do you mean by React wrapper? All 3 are integrated through CKEditor 4 plugins and React CKEditor 4 integration is based on editor itself and works with any set of plugins. As for possible solutions you can use official ones (Easy Image, CKFinder), 3rd-party or implement you own.